# C# MongoDB, LINQ unable to match by Id

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, linq, nosql

I'm using MongoDB.Driver (2.12.4) while trying to stay away from Bson documents. Apart from the Mongo collection methods I use LINQ for all of my queries.

I have a baseclass like this:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
}
```

And a subclass like this:

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public User(string name = "", string email = "")
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    Name = name;
    Email = email;
}
```

And my database class is initialized like this:

```
class Database
{
    const string MongoConnection = "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.mongodb.net/";
    public static MongoClient Client { get; private set; }
    public static IMongoDatabase Directory { get; private set; }
    public static IMongoCollection<User> Users { get; private set; }

    public Database()
    {
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
        Client = new MongoClient(MongoConnection);
        Directory = Client.GetDatabase("DB");
        Users = Directory.GetCollection<User>("users");
    }
}
```

What has been working so far:

```
Database.Users.InsertOne((new User("name", "email@domain.com")); //cloud.mongodb.com shows {_id : UUID('a12937ba-7a7c-4c5d-a8ff-4049e9878ca3')}
var document = Database.Users.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Email == "email@domain.com").FirstOrDefault();
Database.Users.AsQueryable().ToList().Where(x => x.Id == document.Id).FirstOrDefault()
```

But none of the following is working:

```
Database.Users.Find(x => x.Id == document.Id).FirstOrDefault(); //returns null
Database.Users.AsQueryable().Any(x => x.Id == document.Id); //returns false
Database.Users.ReplaceOne(x => x.Id == document.Id, document); //returns MatchedCount = 0
```

So it seems that as soon as I use .ToList then everything works as expected. But if I use .AsQueryable, .Find, .Any or .ReplaceOne directly on the collection then it's not able to perform a match between Ids.

I am not able to find a similar question that does not use [BsonId] or [BsonElement] and does not make use of filters and builders. If I understand correctly the MongoDB.Driver is supposed to do the mapping automatically, and for every property it works except the Id. What am I missing?

PS: I am not using Entity Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this on start of the app:

```cs
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;
```

this makes the query possible with the Guid Id.
it does have a comment of "obsolete" on the latest driver but i guess that's a bug.

Comment: Really.. I had this before, but due to that warning I replaced it with "BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));"

 Do you know the difference between these two? Should I leave out BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer or use both? (without it Mongo will store my GUID as a legacy UUID of Binary type 0x03)

Comment: It have the same effect as the GuidRepresentationMode, I don't know how they implement the driver, but it seems the RegisterSerialize() only affect the insertion and not the queries - that is the bug in the driver, they believe it is obsolete. if you use RegisterSerialize() and the BsonDefault it works as you expect with UUID type 04.
see here for RepresentationMode - http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/reference/bson/guidserialization/guidrepresentationmode/guidrepresentationmode/